# Java Single LinkedList

Tags: java

I am a CS student and I was wondering is this code looks clean. I tested it and it passed every tested but I think the `delete(Node node)` is a bit long, I did not find a way to reduce it

**Node class**

```
public class Node {
      private int data;
      private Node next;
      Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
      }

      public int getValue(){
        return this.data;
      }

      public void setNext(Node next){
        this.next = next;
      }

      public Node nextNode(){
        return this.next;
      }
    }
```

**LinkedList class**

```
public class LinkedList {
  Node head;
  Node tail;
  int size = 0;


  public void add(Node node){
    if(tail == null && head == null){
      tail = node;
      head = node;

    } else{
      tail.setNext(node);
      tail = tail.nextNode();
    }
    size ++;
  }

  public int getSize(){
    return this.size;
  }
  public int getTail(){
    if(tail == null){
      return -1;
    } else {
      return tail.getValue();
    }
  }

  public void delete(Node node){
    if(isPresent(node)){
      if(size == 1){
        this.tail = null;
        this.head = null;
        size = 0;
      }
      else if(node == head){
        head = head.nextNode();
        size --;
      }

      else if(node == tail){
        Node iterator = head;
        while(iterator.nextNode().nextNode() != tail){
          iterator = iterator.nextNode();
        }
        tail = iterator.nextNode();
        iterator.nextNode().setNext(null);
        size --;
      }

      else{
        Node iterator = head;
        while(iterator.nextNode() != node){
          iterator = iterator.nextNode();
        }
        iterator.setNext(iterator.nextNode().nextNode());
        size --;
      }
    }
  }

  public int getHead(){
    if(head == null){
      return -1;
    } else {
      return head.getValue();
    }
  }


  public void printList(){
    Node iterator = head;

    while(iterator != null){
      System.out.println(iterator.getValue());
      iterator = iterator.nextNode();
    }
  }

  public boolean isPresent(Node node){
    if(head == null){
      return false;
    }

    else if(head.getValue() == node.getValue()){
      return true;
    }

    else {
      Node iterator = head;
      while(iterator != null){
        if(iterator.getValue() == node.getValue()){
          return true;
        }
        iterator = iterator.nextNode();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the cases for `delete` can be reduced.

```
  public void delete(Node node) {
    Node prior = null;
    Node current = head;
    while (current != node && current != null) {
      prior = current;
      current = current.next;
    }
    if (current != null) {
      if (prior == null) {
        head = current.next;
      } else {
        prior.next = current.next;
      }
      --size;
      if (current == tail) {
        tail = prior;
      }
    }
  }
```

In general one would keep Node an internal non-public class, for instance one would not
like people to play with the `next` field. Hence I would propose:

```
  public void delete(int value) {
    Node prior = null;
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null && current.value != value) {
      prior = current;
      current = current.next;
    }
    if (current != null) {
      if (prior == null) {
        head = current.next;
      } else {
        prior.next = current.next;
      }
      --size;
      if (current == tail) {
        tail = prior;
      }
    }
  }
```

For the rest:

- A tab of 4 spaces is still my favorite, probably still mainstream.
- `iterator` is an unlucky naming, as there exist an Iterator in java, with a collection method `iterator()`. I used `current`.

And (as goodie) what about `System.out.println(list);`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
      if (sb.length() >= 1) {
          sb.append(", ");
      }
      sb.append(current.value);
      current = current.next;
    }
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out by @Joop Eggen, you should decide if `Node` is part of the interface or not.  As it stands, you can directly access the value of `head` and `tail` via the accessors (`getHead`,`getTail`), however you can't get at any of the other values in the other values you've stored in the `LinkedList` unless you happen to have kept track of the `Node` that you inserted into it.  Try writing `printList` in a client class for your linked list.

```
  public void setNext(Node next){
  public Node nextNode(){
```

These methods represent a property, so they'd usually be named consistently, i.e. `getNext`, `setNext`.  However, if you go down the route of making `Node` an internal class, I'd get rid of them altogether and directly access the fields.

It's also worth mentioning that at the moment, even though the list stores integers, you can't safely store -1 in it because you're using this as an error value when returning head/tail for an empty list.  It'd be better to throw an exception in such a situation, or return an `Optional<Integer>`.

Comment: `OptionalInt` rather. I thought of it too. Your more elaborate answer really is worthwile reading.